# How to include or wrap the file or file content or file object when using Softlayer Object Storage REST API

Tags: openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I am using Softlayer Object Storage REST API.
I was told that below command line using CURL has been successful.

```
$ curl -i -XPUT -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkabcd" --data-binary "Created for testing REST client" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_abcd/container2/file10.txt
```

I wish to upload files using Javascript so I have no clue how do I wrap the file in my request.
Anyone please provide an example? A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here some ideas and examples that can help you:

- [CORS](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/cors.html#test-cors-page)
- [How to consume a RESTful service using
  jQuery](http://www.lm-tech.it/Blog/post/2013/05/08/How-to-consume-a-RESTful-service-using-jQuery.aspx)
- [JavaScript REST client Library
  [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921942/javascript-rest-client-library)
- https://ricardo147.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/image001.png

However, there is a customer who was not able to make rest request through Javascript. I will investigate about it, I will let you know any news.

- [(Softlayer, Open Stack Swift) How to solve cross domain origin with
  object storage
  api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493793/softlayer-open-stack-swift-how-to-solve-cross-domain-origin-with-object-stora)